# Ошибка: The above error occurred in the <styled.button> component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Создаю библиотеку компонентов. В этой библиотеки создала один компонент, подключила локально через npm link к своему проекту, все работа, компонент отображался.
Но когда я решила подключить styled-components для создания компонента. Вот мой компонент.

```
import React, {FC} from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import './mytbc.css'

export interface MyButtonProps{
    color:string;
    big?:boolean;
}

const MyCom: FC<MyButtonProps> = ({children,  color, big, ...props}) => {
    const MyCommon = styled.button`
        background:${color};
        padding:10px;
    `
    return (
        <MyCommon>
            {children}
        </MyCommon>
    )
}
export default MyCom
```

То в консоли появились ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит мой package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-component-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "*",
    "styled-components": ">=5.3.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Как исправить эти ошибки и с чем они связаны?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с тем, что где-то в приложении вы вызываете хук вне реакт компонента, возможно вы делаете это в другом компоненте. Также надо вынести создание MyCommon из тела компонента. поставьте его рядом с интерфейсом MyButtonProps. Чтобы прокинуть пропс в styled-component, вы можете посмотреть, как это делается в документации https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props